# How do I create a circle with an exclamation mark inside in iText?

Tags: java, itext

As a form of warning symbol, I would like to add an exclamation mark within a filled circle as graphics to a pdf, although I have yet to succeed. Help would be much appreciated!

And as a follow-up question: How would I put such a symbol in the lower right corner of a PdfPTable cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sound like you actually would like to have that symbol as a character in some font to be able to handle it like any other character.

If that is right, you may want to create a Type 3 font with that character. You can do that with iText, cf. section 11.3.2 *Type 3 fonts* of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/), especially the sample [Type3Example.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=200) in which two symbols, a Delta and a Sigma, are created as characters in a Type 3 font and then used.

The essential part, the creation of the characters, is this:

```
Type3Font t3 = new Type3Font(writer, true);
// Delta
PdfContentByte d = t3.defineGlyph('D', 600, 0, 0, 600, 700);
d.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));
d.setColorFill(new GrayColor(0.7f));
d.setLineWidth(100);
d.moveTo(5, 5);
d.lineTo(300, 695);
d.lineTo(595, 5);
d.closePathFillStroke();
//Sigma
PdfContentByte s = t3.defineGlyph('S', 600, 0, 0, 600, 700);
s.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(0x00, 0x80, 0x80));
s.setLineWidth(100);
s.moveTo(595,5);
s.lineTo(5, 5);
s.lineTo(300, 350);
s.lineTo(5, 695);
s.lineTo(595, 695);
s.stroke();

// Use as regular font at size 12
Font f = new Font(t3, 12);
```

All you have to do is create your symbol using lines, curves, circles, ...